# How do I show grants for a username on Mysql?

Tags: mysql, permissions, database, replication

More specifically, how do I show what replication grants is attached to a username?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
mysql> select Host, User, grant_priv, Repl_slave_priv, Repl_client_priv from mysql.user;
```

This should give you output similar to that below:

```
+-----------+------------+------------+-----------------+------------------+
| Host      | User       | grant_priv | Repl_slave_priv | Repl_client_priv |
+-----------+------------+------------+-----------------+------------------+
| localhost | root       | Y          | Y               | Y                |
| localhost | dlo        | Y          | Y               | Y                |
+-----------+------------+------------+-----------------+------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

For schema based privileges

`SELECT * FROM information_schema.schema_privileges`